# Terraform: add a message to queue

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, devops

I create queue inside storage by the following way:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_queue" "myqueue" {
  name                  = "myqueue"
  storage_account_name  = "${azurerm_storage_account.sto1.name}"
}
```

but for this queue I want to add init message (it's like a marker, when I sync with external resource last time and need to get data from the last execution). How can I configure it in terraform file?

Comment: You most likely can't. What would (you expect to) happen during the next deployment?

Comment: Terraform is supposed to describe the infrastructure, a message is not part of the infrastructure but is some state within it, terraform does not care about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a use case for [remote-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/remote-exec.html).

Generally when using remote-exec, using a [null provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource) is recommended. This lets you have closer control over what triggers the provider, rather than being dependent on the logic of the cloud service you're integrating it with.